# PostgreSQL OSError: Multiple exceptions: [Errno 111] Connect call failed ('127.0.0.1', 5432), [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, discord.py

So I'm new to PostgreSQL and I made my server and database and the table and stuff then I do back to repl.it discord.py and I tried running this:

```
async def create_db_pool():
  client.pg_con = await asyncpg.create_pool(database= "mainbank", user = "postgres", password = password)

client.loop.run_until_complete(create_db_pool())
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 204, in <module>
    client.loop.run_until_complete(create_db_pool())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 616, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "main.py", line 39, in create_db_pool
    client.pg_con = await asyncpg.create_pool(database= "mainbank", user = "postgres", password = password)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/asyncpg/pool.py", line 407, in _async__init__
    await self._initialize()
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/asyncpg/pool.py", line 435, in _initialize
    await first_ch.connect()
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/asyncpg/pool.py", line 127, in connect
    self._con = await self._pool._get_new_connection()
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/asyncpg/pool.py", line 477, in _get_new_connection
    con = await connection.connect(
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/asyncpg/connection.py", line 1980, in connect
    return await connect_utils._connect(
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/asyncpg/connect_utils.py", line 677, in _connect
    raise last_error
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/asyncpg/connect_utils.py", line 661, in _connect
    con = await _connect_addr(
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/asyncpg/connect_utils.py", line 634, in _connect_addr
    tr, pr = await compat.wait_for(connector, timeout=timeout)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/asyncpg/compat.py", line 103, in wait_for
    return await asyncio.wait_for(fut, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/tasks.py", line 494, in wait_for
    return fut.result()
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/asyncpg/connect_utils.py", line 544, in _create_ssl_connection
    tr, pr = await loop.create_connection(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1033, in create_connection
    raise OSError('Multiple exceptions: {}'.format(
OSError: Multiple exceptions: [Errno 111] Connect call failed ('127.0.0.1', 5432), [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address
```

What is wrong? It is my side or is it PostgreSQL? I have the Host as localhost and the port as 5432 (all default)

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you have too many TCP connections on that machine. Whenever you `connect(2)` to establish a TCP connections (and you didn't `bind(2)` the socket to a port), the network socket is assigned an [ephemeral port](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ephemeral_port) by the operating system. If there is no free ephemeral port on the machine, you get the error `EADDRNOTAVAIL`:

> `EADDRNOTAVAIL`
>
> (Internet  domain  sockets) The socket referred to by `sockfd` had not previously been bound to an address and, upon attempting to
> bind it to an ephemeral port, it was determined that all port numbers in the ephemeral port range are currently in use.  See the
> discussion of `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_local_port_range` in `ip(7)`.

Either open fewer TCP connections or increase the range for ephemeral ports.

Comment: So how would I resolve this?  I'm no expert on ports and sockets and stuff. Am I suppose to go to my computer and change the TCP connections, or is it the machine on PostgreSQL?

Comment: It is the client machine. Get someone who knows about networking. You could increase the limit, like the answer says, but chances are that you have tons and tons of outgoing network connections (a leak somewhere?). Check that first.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same exact error running a Python FastAPI app in a Docker container trying to connect to another container with `http3.AsyncClient` (looks in both cases `asyncio` library is used) to GET a response from another app. The answer above by @Laurenz Albe directed me to

```
docker system prune -a
```

The app ran after that. I also can reproduce this error if trying to connect to `127.0.0.1` but container not on the `host` network.

Comment: Use this with caution. It will remove - all stopped containers
  - all networks not used by at least one container
  - all images without at least one container associated to them
  - all build cache

Comment: @CaseySchneider, thank you, you are right. I did not think about it, was in dev environment.